# How to Implement UISearchBar searching from firestore in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to implement a search functionality in my app. I want it that when a user searches for a specific shop in the search bar, it would search the firestore database and populate the tableview with the specific shop he entered.

but i am stuck in the searchBar function and how I would query the firestore to retrieve and store the text that the user enters in the search bar.

here is my code so far:

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        filteredShops = []
        db.collection("Shops").whereField("name", isLessThanOrEqualTo: searchText).addSnapshotListener{ (query, error) in
            if error != nil {return}
            guard let doucments = query?.documents else {return}
            for doc in doucments {
                
                self.sName = doc["name"] as? String
                self.sLoc = doc["location"] as? String
                self.sImg = doc["ShopHeaderImg"] as? String
                
                self.filteredShops.append(self.sName!)
                self.filteredShops.append(self.sLoc!)
                self.filteredShops.append(self.sImg!)
                
                
            }
        }
        print("is typing")
    }
}




extension SearchTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredShops.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = searchTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchShop")! as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredShops[0]
        return cell
    }
    
   

}
```

how can i implement this with firestore database?

Comment: You're asking how to query the database, or how the display the result?

Comment: @Pancho please view my edited question, i am asking how to query the database and display the result in the correct manner. above method i am showing did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is some pseudo code

Create yourself something that is easier to work with, to serve you as a data model

```
   struct Shop {
       let name: String?
       let location: String?
       let image: String?
  
       init(from document: Document) {
           name = document["name"] as? String
           location = document["location"] as? String
           image = document["ShopHeaderImg"] as? String
       }
   }
```

Then in your view controller add the data source

```
var shops: [Shop] = []
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    db.collection("Shops")
      .whereField("name", contains: searchText)
      .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (query, error) in
        // make sure you capture self weak as it may lead to memory leak
        guard let self = self, let documents = query?.documents else { return }           
        // simply transform your Documents to Shops and update your dataSource
        self.shops = documents.map { Shop(from: $0) }
        // Reload your table view and show the result
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}

extension SearchTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return shops.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = searchTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchShop")! as UITableViewCell
       let shop = shops[indexPath.row]
       cell.textLabel?.text = shop.name
       return cell
   }
}
```

Comment: amazing answer, it works now. is there a way where i can make it that it starts with a prefix? so if user starts typing "St" it would display all shops with the prefix "St" in the beginning?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on how to query for it. I am not too familiar with firestore